# Create XML based quiz

Tags: xml, apache-flex, xul

I need too create quiz app using xml for database for questions and xul or flax for interface, quiz should have 3 types of questions : single answer (radio), multianswer (checkbox) and open (textfield).
I really don't know how to import questions from xml, to xul/flex
Also i need to save the answers to txt/xml file
Can any1 help me please ? 
The xml database is something like this

```
<question type="q1" number="1"> // q1 - radio q2 - checkbox q3 - text
<qHead>This is a question ?</qhead>
<option>option one</option>
<option>option two</option>
<option>option three</option>
<option>option four</option>
</question>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somebody recently put together a Flex Mobile demo called "[SurveyApe](http://blogs.adobe.com/koestler/2010/11/open-source-flex-hero-app-surveyape.html)".  It is targeted for the mobile SDK, but barely anything about it (other than layout and form factor) is specific to mobile.

It might be a good start?

Answer (score 0):

What technology is used on the server side? How data are exposed from the server (REST, SOAP, ...)?

If it's REST based, you can use the HTTPService class to load your XML.
If it's SOAP based, use the Webservice class.

Usually, people use RemoteObject to call direclty methods on the server side. The nice thing with RemoteObject is that data are transfered in a binary format and are automatically serialized/unserialized

Answer (score 0):

First, decide which technology you want to use (XUL or Flex).  You can search online to compare these two technologies.

Then, read tutorials about creating simple interfaces with those platforms.

If you get stuck, come back and ask a more specific question.